# Insert a data set in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-mining

I am using Oracle Data Miner 11g Release 2 to predict poker hand. The data set I am using is UCI poker hand data set from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Poker+Hand.

I am new to oracle so I refer to the oracle tutorial in http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/bidw/datamining/ODM11gR2.htm for data mining

So far I have managed to create workflow in the tutorial but am stuck on setting up the data source.

How can I insert the UCI poker hand data set and add it to the data source?

Comment: Nothing is urgent on StackOverflow. Questions are answered by volunteers. This is not a support site and you have no SLA with us. That goes double for homework questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle data sources are tables. So you need to create tables to hold the UCI data. There are two data sets: a training set and a real set. You could create one table to hold both but it's probably easier to have a separate table for each.

The data sets comprise eleven numeric columns so the structure is straightforward:

```
create table training_poker_hand (
    S1 number,
    C1 number,
    S2 number,
    C2 number,
    S3 number,
    C3 number,
    S4 number,
    C4 number,
    S5 number,
    C5 number,
    CLASS number
)
```

The table for the real data will have the same structure.

Once you have the tables, you need to insert the data. The UCI data sets files of comma-separated values. The tutorial uses SQL Developer, so assuming you're using that tool it's easy enough to import CSV data into a table: [just follow That Jeff Smith's instructions](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/).

Comment: Thanks.tutorial was a great help.